# Can't select option from nx bash command

Tags: android, windows, cmd, build, emulation

I currently have an web app that I build with Capacitor for Android and iOS. But when I run `nx run myapp:run:android` everything executes fine until I need to select the emulator in the options. I can't use my arrow keys and also can't press return. With other commands where I need to select something it works just finde. Also the command runs perfectly. So any idea what the problem could be? I used Windows cmd, VScode and git bash and also restarted my computer. Also other similar commands for nx (like sync) work.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue. It looks like it is related to nx:run-commands. I posted a message in their slack channel already. Let's hope someone answers soon. :-)

Until this is fixed you can run it manually:

cd apps/your-app

npx --package=@capacitor/cli cap run android